# Parameter 'browserType' is required by @Configuration on method before but has not been defined in src\test\resources\testng.xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parameters, testng, testng-dataprovider

When running Selenium case, I want firefox and chrome at the same build. My testng.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

  <test name="Browser Compatibility Test Cases--firefox" thread-count="1" preserve-order="false">
       <parameter name="browserType" value="firefox" />
       <classes>
           <class name="com.yeetrack.selenium.test.ParameterTest" />
       </classes>
  </test>

    <test name="Browser Compatibility Test Cases--chrome" thread-count="1" preserve-order="false">
        <parameter name="browserType" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.yeetrack.selenium.test.ParameterTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And my test case:

```
public class ParameterTest {
    @Parameters("browserType")
    @BeforeMethod
    public void before(String browser)
    {
        System.out.println(browser);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "KeywordDataProvider", dataProviderClass = KeywordData.class)
    public void test(String keyword)
    {
        System.out.println(keyword);
    }
}
```

But I got an error:

```
before(com.yeetrack.selenium.test.ParameterTest)  Time elapsed: 0.222 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'browserType' is required by @Configuration on method before
but has not been defined in src\test\resources\testng.xml
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:109)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:264)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:427)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:607)
```

When running, browserType=firefox, it passed. But when browserType=chrome, it failed. I can't use @Parameters and DataProvider at the same time? When I change my case to :

```
@Test //no DataProvider
public void test()
            {
                System.out.println("Hello world"));
            }
```

It passed! Why? thx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the OP's comment solution as an answer, to make it clearer for future visitors.

In the pom.xml, the original poster added testng instead of surefire:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

This is instead of surefire-testng:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```